# rails routing with just the id in the url and form edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

My application has an `Article` model and url for articles is like this

```
  www.mysite.com/21
  www.mysite.com/22
```

In the `routes.rb` I have set

```
map.article '/:id', :controller => 'articles', :action => 'show'
```

Everything works fine.

While editing the article, the form doesn't get updated as the form action is pointed to the article path

For example, this is the form generated

```
<form action="/48" class="edit_article" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_article_48" method="post">
.
.
.
</form>
```

When I submit the form, it just goes to the article show page.

This is my _form.html.erb partial

```
<% form_for @article, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
.
.
.
<% end %>
```

Has anyone faced this kind of problem before? Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your routing so that get requests retrive the article while the put/post requests invoke some other actions that will update/create articles.

refer [rails guide for routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html) for more information. BTW i am assuming that you are using rails 2.

I would recommend you to use RESTful routing. Like:

```
map.root :controller => 'articles'
map.resources :article
```

then:

```
GET www.mysite.com/21 will go to show
PUT www.mysite.com/21 will go to update
POST www.mysite.com/21 will go to create
```

..etc

Comment: no, it dint work out... I have a different controller mapped for map.root. Other thing is map.resources :article generates routes like article/21 etc etc hence i had given map.article '/:id', :controller => 'articles', :action => 'show'